# Image as a signal representation

Tags: image, matlab, signal-processing

I have an image A(RGB) and B which is a gray scaled 256*256 size. How does one represent a gray scaled and an RGB image as a signal with X axis showing the time and Y axis the amplitude or the values? I have attached a picture of how I want to represent the image as a signal. Now, I really do not know if it is possible to do the same with an image. The representation can be a continuous form. I do not know what values are to be represented on Y axis, if it is the gray levels then what would be the difference between this plot and histogram (which will be a plot of gray levels vs number of pixels). The objective of this representation is to transmit the image as signal over a wireless communication channel using hardware and to show the effects of channel noise and denoising mechanism at the receiver section.[image: signal]

Comment: This both doesn't make sense and also has nothing to do with matlab...? An image is just a 2D signal, the X and Y directions are analogous to 'time' and the pixel intensities to amplitude...

Comment: What does that mean? You want to take a 2D data structure and plot it as a 1D data structure... so what happens to all the other information? Or do you just want to plot single row of the image? Or are you looking for `imshow`? Or do you want to take a shadow of the image like `sum(image)`?

Comment: I have edited my question and added more sentences. Please have a look. I have tried my best to explain the purpose. I am absolutely unsure if this can be done for images, hence the question is posted.

Comment: Do you want to transfer the bits that make up the image, you mean?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to take a series of values, representing a sampled signal, and produce a plot similar to the image you show here?

Comment: I want to represent the bits or intensity value of the image in the form of 1D signal.

Comment: "The objective of this representation is to transmit the image as signal over a wireless communication channel..." This is the only relevant sentence in your question! Plotting a graph has absolutely nothing to do with it! Just look up file transfer protocols! Its a pretty solved problem. Or else reshape your image to be 1D and then reshape it back to 2D on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to plot a 2D signal (image) in 1D, but you can vectorize your grayscale image. Something like...

```
vectorizedImg = img(:);
plot(vectorizedImg);
```

Then, decide what you want to do your with RGB image, because that's a 3-D matrix. e.g. take the average, sum it, or whatever. You'll have your 1-D plot, but the display will probably not convey any useful information to the user, :).

Comment: The display is meaningless for both RGB and BW, you might as well just vectorize the RGB image the same way i.e. RGB(:)

Answer (score 0):

One common method to transmit an uncompressed 2D image down a single/1D communication channel is to rasterizer the image, and send it either one pixel row or one pixel column at a time.  In your example, send the top row of 256 pixels and repeat 256 times.  For color, you can either repeat the whole raster 3 times for RGB, or interleave the components  by sending one level for each of the 3 components per pixel.  For a binary digital communication channel, the components can be quantized, with each bit of the quantized result sent bit serially.  The sent data format commonly also includes some synchronization and/or framing information.